# How to fit gaussian with Matlab with given height

Tags: matlab, gaussian

I am currently unable to have accurate gaussian fit. How can I fix the height? (see picture).

```
ft=fit(x,y,'gauss2') 
Co=coeffvalues(ft)
sigma=Co(3)/sqrt(2)  
mu = Co(2)
C=Co(1)

plot(X,C*exp(-(X - mu).^2 / (2*sigma^2))+min(y), '-r')
```

Comment: I don't see a picture.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me on R2013a but then I don't know what your data is. You might try playing with [`fitoptions`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fitoptions.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try **lsqcurvefit** to do single or multiple Gaussian fitting accurately.

```
x = lsqcurvefit(fun,x0,xdata,ydata)
```

**fun** is your Gaussian function, **x0** holds the initial value of the Gaussian parameters (mu, sigma, height, etc). **fun(x0)** return the gaussian in vector/array form. When the routine returns, the fitted parameters are in **x**. You can customize the function **fun** to fit one Gaussian or multiple Gaussians to your data.

[Matlab document of lsqcurvefit](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqcurvefit.html)

In my case, I use the following routine to do multiple Gaussian fitting:

```
x0 = [1000;10.6;0.6;
     1100;12.8;0.7; %3 Gaussians
     300;10;2];     %each row is the height, mu, sigma of one Gaussian

options = optimset('TolFun',10e-6,'MaxFunEvals',150000);
%lb, ub are the similar matrix as x0 that define lower and upper bound of x.
[x, resnorm] = lsqcurvefit(@myfit, x0, xdata, ydata, lb, ub);
```

The **myfit** function that calculates superposition of multiple Gaussians:

```
function [ F ] = myfit(x, xdata)
    F = zeros(1,size(xdata,2));
    len = size(x,1);
    for i = 1:3:len
        F = F + x(i)*gauss(xdata, x(i+1), x(i+2));
    end
end
```

The Gaussian function:

```
function [ g ] = gauss(x, mu, sigma)
    g = exp(-0.5*((x-mu)/sigma).^2);
end
```