# fitting gaussian distribution to data

Tags: matlab, normalization, curve-fitting, gaussian

I have a vector `y` containing 1440 values (values are between 0-1) that looks like a Gaussian distribution.
Therefore I would like to find the best fitting gaussian distribution to have a model.

```
x=1:1440;
[sigma_,mu_] = gaussfit(x,y);
norm = normpdf(x,mu_,sigma_);
```

My problem is that the values in norm are way smaller than the values in `y`, i.e. value in `norm` are of the order of `10-3` while values in y are between `0 1`.

I have then to add an extra step in order to normalize between 0 and 1 the  values in norm.

```
norm_data = (norm - min(norm)) / ( max(norm) - min(norm) );
```

Is my procedure correct? (estimation of sigma and mu, normpdf, normalization)
Is there a way to get directly a fit to the original data expressing the probability?

`y` can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3vXKJ_zYaCJQmx6S3h3Z3IzWUE/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using this [`gaussfit`](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35122-gaussian-fit/content/gaussfit.m), if you check the head of the function:

```
% REMARKS:
% The function does not always converge in which case try to use initial
% values sigma0, mu0. Check also if the data is properly scaled, i.e. p.d.f
% should approx. sum up to 1
```

Which means that before fitting you need to make sure that `sum(y)==1+err` being err something small.

Your `y` has a `sum(y)` of `470.1964`, which is kind of far from `1`. Normalize your data so the sum is equal to one before fitting it.

**EDIT**

Indeed the fucntion does normalize if the data is not (more or less, it accepts data in range 0.5-1.5). And works perfectly fine. As `y` is normalized inside the function, If you want to compare the result `norm` to `y` you need to normalize `y` or denormalize `norm`.

```
 % normalize y
 plot(x,norm,x,y./sum(y))
 % denormalize norm
 plot(x,norm*sum(y),x,y)
```

in either case (but different scale):

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but the function gaussfit already normalize the data if they are not... my problem is that the estimated pdf has values that are way smaller than the empirical one...

Comment: @gabboshow I copied the text from the function. Which means the function **DOES NOT** normalize the data. Else the text wont be there. Read again my answer , normalizing `y` should be straightforward. Note that if you are dealing with statistics, `y` **must** be normalized, else its conceptually wrong.

Comment: Plase see line 56 of function gaussfit

Comment: OK, so if this is the case I would scale norm as I was doing before to have a probability between 0 and 1. Thanks.

Comment: @gabboshow dont scale the norm to be `[0 1]` range. As the `gaussfit` does not require `y` to have exactly 1 pdf (it can be between 0.5 to 1.5) its better if you scale it as I shown, multiplying it by `sum(y)`. In the example you posted it does not matter, but it will matter for other values of `y`.

Comment: My original data is a probability distribution [0 1]. The fitted data (gaussian) needs to be a probability distribution as well...I can't have values bigger than 1.

Comment: Can you please explain in which case I would have problems in doing this?

Comment: with any `y` where `sum(y)` is between `[0.5 1.5]`, mo matter the maximum value of `y`. Also, doing `norm_data=norm*sum(y)` is even less verbose than the way you do it, more elegant! @gabboshow

Answer (score 0):

gaussfit(x,y) fits a normalized Gaussian to the data. If your data is not normalized this cannot work. The question of how to fit it properly is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586006/how-to-fit-gaussian-with-matalb-with-given-height)!